# Window freeze after pygame program runs

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.6

I am learning pygame and have been working on examples given in 'Python Crash Course' book by Eric Matthews (https://g.co/kgs/WP5fay). I have installed pygame version 1.9.3 on macOS High Sierra.

When I run the following program, a window opens and when I click 'X' to close it, the window freezes and the curses keeps circling and I get a python not responding error in activity monitor. I have tried a number of option to fix the problem but it is not going away.

```
import pygame
import sys
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game() #when I run this function, a window opens and freezes a couple of seconds after
```

Comment: It works fine for me, same configuration. Is this behavior consistent for you?

Comment: Do you use the IDLE IDE? Then try to call `pygame.quit()` before `sys.exit()`. Also, `pygame.display.flip()` should be in the while loop, but that has probably nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @HavanAgrawal yes, it is not working for me.

Comment: @skrx: Thanks for your response and sorry about the indentation error on pygame.display.flip(). I am working in jupyter notebook. I have tried saving this as .py file and run using 'python gamefile.py'. Adding pygame.quit() does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to terminate the application loop and uninitialize all pygame modules with [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html):

```py
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        pygame.display.flip()
 
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```